# Paid traffic reported as organic in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

Google Analytics reports paid traffic from Bing, Google, FB, and Yahoo as organic.

The AdWords account is linked properly and auto-tagging has been enabled, there doesn't seem to be any reason why this is happening?

Here is an example of the script for one of the paid URLs that's listed as organic:

`...document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create','UA-XXXXXXXX-XX','auto');ga('require','GTM-XXXXXX');ga('send','pageview');`